# uWSGI Segmentation Fault Prevents Web Server Running

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, uwsgi, wsgi

I am currently running a web server through two containers:

- NGINX Container: Serves HTTPS requests and redirects HTTP to HTTPS. HTTPS requests are passed through uwsgi to the django app.
- Django Container: Runs the necessary Django code.

When running `docker-compose up --build`, everything compiles correctly until uWSGI raises a Segmentation Fault.

```
....
django3_1  | Python main interpreter initialized at 0x7fd7bce0d190
django3_1  | python threads support enabled
django3_1  | your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
django3_1  | your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
django3_1  | mapped 145840 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
django3_1  | *** Operational MODE: single process ***
django3_1  | !!! uWSGI process 7 got Segmentation Fault !!!
test_django3_1 exited with code 1
```

Would appreciate if there's any advice, as I'm not able to see into the container for debugging purposes when it is starting up, therefore I don't know where this segmentation fault is occurring.

The SSL certificates have been correctly set up.

Answer (score 1):

The django3 container was running on a python:3.9-alpine image. This installs Python 3.9.2 on the container. There appear to be some issue between uWSGI and Python dependencies on this version. Rolling the container back to python:3.8-alpine resolved the dependency version mismatch.